# How should the [animation] tag be used? What should we write as tag usage guidance in the tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I would like to request community feedback on the [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) tag usage guidance. I’ve noticed that this tag is being used as a meta tag; that is, it is applied to questions that are not about animation, where it just happens that the movie or TV show being asked about is animated. This goes against the general SE policy that meta tags are explicitly discouraged, as explained by Jeff Atwood, SE co-founder, in the Stack Overflow Blog: [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

To prevent the tag from being misused as a meta tag, I’ve [suggested the following edit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94698) to the [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) tag wiki excerpt.

Before:

> Movies or shows that consist entirely of either hand drawn or computer drawn/generated content.

After:

> For questions about the animation process used in movies and TV shows. Do not use this tag if your question is not about animation, even if the movie or TV show you're asking about is animated. Animation is a method by which still images are manipulated to create the illusion of movement. This can be done using a variety of techniques, including traditional animation, stop-motion animation, and computer animation.

However, after this edit was approved, I noticed that the tag was also being used for questions about animated movies or TV shows *in general*, sometimes as the sole tag, and the above usage guidance would not apply to those questions, since they don't have a specific movie or TV show tag. So I’ve [suggested another edit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94878) to also cover that usage (the part that I’ve changed is bolded):

> For questions about the animation process used in movies and TV shows, **or animated movies or TV shows in general. Otherwise, don't use this tag**, even if the movie or TV show you're asking about is animated. […]

However, [this edit was rejected by a community moderator](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/94878) as it “does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.”

I would appreciate the community's input on this matter. **What should our tag usage guidance for the [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) tag be?** (Please note the [above-mentioned SE policy on meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for the tag usage guidance.)

Answer (score 1):

The [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) tag wiki excerpt could be something like this. Please let me know if you have any feedback, and feel free to suggest improvements.

> For questions about the animation process used in movies and TV shows, or animated movies or TV shows in general. Otherwise, don't use this tag, even if the movie or TV show you're asking about is animated. Animation is a method by which still images are manipulated to create the illusion of movement. This can be done using a variety of techniques, including traditional animation, stop-motion animation, and computer animation.

Rationale:

> For questions about the animation process used in movies and TV shows

Encourages usage of the tag if the question is *about animation* (non-meta tag usage). For example, questions about why or how specific scene(s) were animated a certain way, and the like.

> or animated movies or TV shows in general

Allows usage of [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) as a tag for questions about animated movies or TV shows *in general*, since they don't have a specific movie or TV show tag. E.g., [What was the longest successful Primetime cartoon prior to The Simpsons?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23703/1006), [First animated movie to put "bloopers" in end credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62528/1006), [Ants are stealing our picnic!](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57543/1006), etc.

> Otherwise, don't use this tag, even if the movie or TV show you're asking about is animated.

Discourages usage of [animation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) as a meta tag, e.g., using it for any animated movie or TV show even if the question has nothing to do with animation, like plot explanation questions.